# Unresolved reference 't' ? Unresolved reference 'w' Помогите решить

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
e = input("залезть  в капсулу и выбрать время и номер (да или нет)")
if  e == "да":
    t = input("выберите год")
    w = input("выберите номер 1 либо 2(вы сейчас находитесь во вселенной номер 2)")
    if t =="1945" and w =="1":
     print ("вы перенеслись в СССР день 8 мая .Из громко говорителей говорили про какуй-то победу ")
     print("the end")
```

Comment: Нет, ну после того как вы поменяли код, такой ошибки уже не должно быть

Comment: @CrazzyElf https://prnt.sc/11iq70b вот скрин

Comment: Так это на код ниже ругается. При ответе "нет" эти переменные будут не определены, а вы их там в `if` проверяете.

Comment: Судя по вашему скриншоту, вы определяете переменные t и w при ответе "да", при ответе "нет" вы сравниваете переменные, но они не определены.